# How to create Python typing classes which can receive additional constraints

Tags: python, typing

I am developing extension to Python typing classes which can obtain extra constraints. I have implemented this using normal classes, but I would like to base it around existing typing classes. Currently, I can do things like:

```
def append(element: Any, list: Array(length='n')) -> Array(length='n + 1'):
  ...
```

But I would like that `Array` is a subclass of existing typing classes. So that I might be able to do something like:

```
def append(element: A, list: List[A](length='n')) -> List[A](length='n + 1'):
  ...
```

Sadly, I cannot find a good way which would allow me to make `List[A](length='n')` return class `List[A]`, just with extra constraints stored somewhere on the class. What I managed to do is this:

```
class ConstrainedTypeMetaclass(typing.GenericMeta):
  def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    #kwargs['_root'] = True
    return super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

  def __repr__(self):
    if hasattr(self, '_raw_constraints'):
      return '{prefix}({raw_constraints})'.format(prefix=super().__repr__(), raw_constraints=self._raw_constraints)
    else:
      return super().__repr__()


class ConstrainedTypeMixin(metaclass=ConstrainedTypeMetaclass):
  def __new__(cls, **raw_constraints):
    return type(cls.__name__, (type(super().__new__(cls)),), {
      '_raw_constraints': raw_constraints,
    })


class ConstrainedSequence(ConstrainedTypeMixin, typing.Sequence[typing.T_co]):
  def __getitem__(self, item):
    pass

  def __len__(self):
    pass
```

It looks like it works, but it feels very hackish. `__repr__` does not look correct (showing that there are some issues with this approach):

- `ConstrainedSequence[A]` outputs `__main__.ConstrainedSequence[~A]`, which is good
- `typing.Sequence[A]` outputs `typing.Sequence[~A]`, which is good
- but `ConstrainedSequence[A](length='a')` outputs `abc.ConstrainedSequence({'length': 'a'})`

Why is not `__main__.ConstrainedSequence[~A]({'length': 'a'})`?

Also, I had to define `__getitem__` and `__len__`, which I do no think I should have to.

And it is unclear how to do non-generic type like this?